# Unable to display exact price in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am new to opencart. I am trying to set the price in admin part but It is not showing as I set in dashboard. It is showing something less than(5% less) the what I entered in admin.

I have set the price of two products in dashboard :

[image]

But when I see the product as follow on the front end :

[image]

I have set display price tax in opencart setting as follow

[image]

Comment: This is not on topic on Stack Overflow I'm afraid... definitely looks like a tax setting though, or maybe a customer group discount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your currencies are correct in System - Localisation - Currencies

you currency should be set as default and with a value of 1.0000